# React-Rails wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have just started implementing [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) to use react with our existing rails project. If I call

render component: 'Table', props: { appt: "Hi" }

in my rails controller, it works fine. If i call:

render component: 'Table', props: { appt: @appointment }

I get: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0). I am not even using this.props.appt in the Component, right now I am just returning a static div and I am still getting this error. Please Help!